# JavaScript - Reposition a DIV incrementally onClick

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, scroll

Very simple code, very simple problem. When a link is pressed, it moves a div either up or down. However, I cannot get it to move incrementally. I know this is a simple syntax error, but google isn't revealing the error of my ways. Anyone willing to enlighten me?

`<a class="galsel" onclick="document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom -='167px';">&laquo;</a>`

`<a class="galsel" onclick="document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom +='167px';">&raquo;</a>`

I already have it so that the div tiles itself vertically, so I'm not worried about it going "too high" or "too low"

Here's what it looks like right now: drainteractive.com/FBD/projects.php

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the error on the page. Could you describe which portion of that link is working incorrectly?

Comment: Are you *sure* it isn't working?

Comment: Does this happen on other browsers?

Comment: It does "work" as in you get to see it scroll. However, there's more than two rows. It needs to continue to scroll up or down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the value from the string containing `px`

```
// Increase by 167
document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom = (parseInt(document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom, 10) + 167) + ' px'

// Decrease by 167
document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom = (parseInt(document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom, 10) - 167) + ' px'

// Abstracted
function addToBottom(el, amount) {
   // You probably add lower and upper bound check conditions
   el.style.bottom = (parseInt(el.style.bottom) + amount) + ' px';
}

var el = document.getElementById('innerscroll');
addToBottom(el, 167);
addToBottom(el, -167);
```

Also be sure to make it work for cases where bottom wasn't set initially

```
var currentBottom = parseInt(document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom) || 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... hrm... I'll play with it and see if I can get it going.

Comment: just use the first 2 lines - the other part is an abstract explanation in general - the main thing is that you can use `parseInt(document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.bottom, 10)` and it will convert the css bottom value to an decimal.

Comment: That's what I did... I'm scratching my head. I must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: @JaredSteffen If it's not working, it's because of your HTML. I am not sure why you are changing `bottom`, using `top` makes a lot more sense in my head. See http://jsfiddle.net/77vee/ For you to be able to set `top,bottom,right,left`, the element must be absolutely or relatively positioned

Comment: Well, using "top" made it move in the opposite direction that I wanted it to move. I know, it's silly. It is absolutely positioned, so that box is ticked. I'm going through my CSS to see if something there is keeping it from happening.

Comment: @JaredSteffen You can't invert the numbers you're passing? -167 instead of 167?

Comment: Instead of `parseInt`, you could use `+variable`

Comment: @ianpgall No you could not `+"11px" ->  NaN`, `parseInt("11px") -> 11`

Comment: Didn't mean directly on "##px"

Comment: @ianpgall So you are suggesting first remove `px` it from string and then use `+` while my example used `parseInt` which already does this? Sorry, but your suggestion just brings confusion to the table, specially in the context of the question

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't bring any confusion - you just explained it. Not that it's important, but `parseInt` rounds any decimal point values, but `+` wouldn't. Just saying

Comment: @ianpgall What you are "Just saying" is not relevant to the conversation, if you want to parse into a float, you use `parseFloat`. Your comment is true in some cases, it just doesn't help clarify the problem at all.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's plenty relevant. It's not the most important thing, oh well. Anyways, that's why there's no reason to get so upset - it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`+='167px'` will concatinate it an it will become `'167px167px167px167px167px'`. Not sure what will result `-='167px'`, but probably will result an error.

Comment: How about explaining how to fix it?

Comment: tru dat... err... homeboy. How would I phrase things to make it increase incrementally, instead of concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rip the 'px' off the string, convert(?) it to an int, then subtract from that.

```
onclick="var mElem = document.getElementById('innerScroll'); mCur = parseInt(mElem.style.bottom.replace('px', 0)); mElem.style.bottom = (mCur-167)+'px'"
```

Naturally, this should all be put into a separate function, who is then called in the onclick, rather than the monstrosity above.

```
function moveUp()
{
var mElem = document.getElementById('innerScroll'); 
var mCur = parseInt(mElem.style.bottom.replace('px', 0)); 
mElem.style.bottom = (mCur-167)+'px';
}
```

...

```
<strike>onlick="moveUp()"</strike>
onclick="moveUp()"
```

My mind must have been somewhere else..

Comment: `parseInt` already ignores px at the end, no need to remove it before passing to `parseInt`

Comment: do you mean `mElem.style.bottom = (mCur-167)+'px';` without the "? Either way, that doesn't seem to do the trick. *dies*

Comment: Bewdy, thanks Juan. :) Shows how much I've needed to use it hehe.

Comment: @JaredSteffen - yes! Thanks. Copy/paste + brain-off error. :)